# Getting value from radiobutton for textbox in C#

Tags: c#, textbox, radio-button

I have a form application in C#. I need to take radiobutton values in textbox.i know the methods are private, i change public but it didnt work. i need to take value1,value2,value3 and value4 with button press.  Can anybody tell me a way for getting values in textboxs....

```
private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double value1;
        if (radioButton1.Checked)
            value1 = 0.9;
        else if (radioButton2.Checked)
            value1 = 0.8;
        else if (radioButton3.Checked)
            value1 = 0.7;
        else if (radioButton4.Checked)
            value1 = 0.3;
        else if (radioButton5.Checked)
            value1 = 0.5;
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Oda Tipi girilmedi.");
    }

    private void groupBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double value2;
        if (radioButton6.Checked)
            value2 = 1;
        else if (radioButton7.Checked)
            value2 = 0.8;
        else if (radioButton8.Checked)
            value2 = 0.6;
        else
            MessageBox.Show("İzolasyon Tipi girilmedi.");
    }

    private void groupBox3_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double value3;
        if (radioButton9.Checked)
            value3 = 0.9;
        else if (radioButton10.Checked)
            value3 = 1;
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Cam Tipi girilmedi.");

    }

    private void groupBox4_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double value4;
        if (radioButton11.Checked)
            value4 = 1;
        else if (radioButton12.Checked)
            value4 = 0.9;
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Formül katsayısı girilmedi.");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox5.Text=Convert.ToString(value1*value2*value3*value4*(Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text))*(Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text))*(Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text)));

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either move the variables (`value1` etc.) to the class scope or put everything in the `button1_Click` event handler like @SteveDanner has suggested or you may write a more generic solution. It can be very easily extendend if you create more options (`RadioButtons`).

```
// Store values for each RadioButton in a dictionary.
private Dictionary<RadioButton, double> values = 
    new Dictionary<RadioButton, double>();

private Dictionary<GroupBox, string> messages = 
    new Dictionary<GroupBox, string>();

public Form1()
{
      InitializeComponent();

      // Associate values with radio buttons.
      values[radioButton1] = 0.9;
      // repeat the same for others...

      // Associate values messages with group boxes.
      messages[groupBox1] = "Oda Tipi girilmedi.";
      // repeat the same for others...
}

#region GroupBox.Enter event handlers.

private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton radioButton = GetSelectedRadioButton(sender as GroupBox);
    if (radioButton == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(messages[sender as GroupBox]);
    }
}

// Here you can either repeat the same for other group boxes 
// or simply assign this event hander to all of them. 
// It will get the right message for each group.

#endregion

// Gets the selected radio button from the specified group.
private void RadioButton GetSelectedRadioButton(GroupBox groupBox)
{
    RadioButton radioButton = 
        groupBox
        .Controls
        .OfType<RadioButton>()
        .Where(rb => rb.Checked)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    return radioButton;
}

// Gets selected value from the specified group.
private double GetSelectedValue(GroupBox groupBox)
{
    RadioButton radioButton = GetSelectedRadioButton(groupBox);
    if (radioButton == null)
    {
        // Nothing selected yet.
        return double.NaN;
    }
    else
    {
        // Get the value from the dictinary.
        return values[radioButton];
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the selected values.
    double value1 = GetSelectedValue(groupBox1);
    double value2 = GetSelectedValue(groupBox2);
    double value3 = GetSelectedValue(groupBox3);
    double value4 = GetSelectedValue(groupBox4);

    // Check other values in the same way.
    if (double.IsNaN(value1))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message[groupBox1]);
    }

    textBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(
    value1 
    * value2 
    * value3 
    * value4 
    * (Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text)) 
    * (Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text)) 
    * (Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text)));

}
```

Comment: @orcanyedal should you have more radio buttons in future you may take a more generic solution into consideration. See the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your values being created from the `RadioButtons` are local variables to the method handlers.  You need to remove your `groupBox_Enter` handlers and just handle the `button1_Click` event like so:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double value1;
    if (radioButton1.Checked)
        value1 = 0.9;
    else if (radioButton2.Checked)
        value1 = 0.8;
    else if (radioButton3.Checked)
        value1 = 0.7;
    else if (radioButton4.Checked)
        value1 = 0.3;
    else if (radioButton5.Checked)
        value1 = 0.5;
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Oda Tipi girilmedi.");
        return; //not sure if this is what you want here?
    }

    double value2;
    if (radioButton6.Checked)
        value2 = 1;
    else if (radioButton7.Checked)
        value2 = 0.8;
    else if (radioButton8.Checked)
        value2 = 0.6;
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Izolasyon Tipi girilmedi.");
        return; //not sure if this is what you want here?
    }

    double value3;
    if (radioButton9.Checked)
        value3 = 0.9;
    else if (radioButton10.Checked)
        value3 = 1;
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cam Tipi girilmedi.");
        return; //not sure if this is what you want here?
    }


    double value4;
    if (radioButton11.Checked)
        value4 = 1;
    else if (radioButton12.Checked)
        value4 = 0.9;
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Formül katsayisi girilmedi.");
        return; //not sure if this is what you want here?
    }

    textBox5.Text=Convert.ToString(value1*value2*value3*value4*(Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text))*(Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text))*(Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text)));

}
```

Comment: its not working, i need to get values from radiobutton to in buttonclick event....

Comment: glad to hear it!  consider marking this as the answer if this is what fixed it.  that way others can benefit in the future